# R - How to convert column of quarters to dates?

Tags: r, date, as.date

I have a csv that contains "Period", which are quarters, and "Percent". After reading the data into R, the "Period" column is "chr" and "Percent" column is "num". I want to change the quarter values to dates, so:

```
for (i in 1:length(sloos_tighten$Period)) {
    sloos_tighten$Period[i] <- paste("Q", substring(sloos_tighten$Period[i], 6), "/", substring(sloos_tighten$Period[i], 1, 4),  sep = "")
    sloos_tighten$Period[i] <- as.Date(as.yearqtr(sloos_tighten$Period[i], format = "Q%q/%Y"))
}
```

where the first line in the for-loop changes the format of the quarter to be readable by as.yearqtr, and the second line changes the quarter to a date. The first line works as intended, but the second line converts the date to a four-digit number. I think this is because "Period" is of type "chr", but I don't know how to change it to date. I have tried to create a new column with type date, but I cannot find any resource online that explains it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
> dput(head(sloos_tighten, 10))
structure(list(Period = c("1990:2", "1990:3", "1990:4", "1991:1", 
"1991:2", "1991:3", "1991:4", "1992:1", "1992:2", "1992:3"), 
    `Large and medium` = c(54.4, 46.7, 54.2, 38.6, 20, 18.6, 
    16.7, 10, 3.5, -3.4), Small = c(52.7, 33.9, 40.7, 31.6, 6.9, 
    8.8, 7, 0, -7.1, -1.7)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

^What the data looks like after import

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow; Please paste a sample of the data into the question using `dput(sloos_tighten)` or `dput(head(sloos_tighten, 10))` to make your question reproducible [MRE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The literal `for` loop is fine in a sense, but unfortunately there are two problems here:

1. There is a `class` problem here: if `$Period` is a string, then when you reassign one of its values with something of `Date` class, the date is then converted into a string. This is because in R `data.frame`'s, with few exceptions, all values in a column must be the same type. That's because a column is (almost always) a *vector*, and R treats vectors as homogenous.

   You can get around this by pre-allocating a vector of type `Date` and assigning it piecemeal:

   ```r
   newdate <- rep(Sys.Date()[NA], nrow(sloos_tighten)) # just to get the class right
   for (i in 1:length(sloos_tighten$Period)) {
     tmp <- paste("Q", substring(sloos_tighten$Period[i], 6), "/", substring(sloos_tighten$Period[i], 1, 4),  sep = "")
     newdate[i] <- as.Date(as.yearqtr(tmp, format = "Q%q/%Y"))
   }
   ```

   (But please, don't use this code, look at #2 below first.)
2. Not a problem per se, but an efficiency: R is good at doing things as a whole vector. If you reassign all of `$Period` in one step, then all is faster.

   ```r
   sloos_tighten$Period <- 
     as.Date(
       paste0(substring(sloos_tighten$Period, 6),
              "/", substring(sloos_tighten$Period, 1, 4)),
       format = "%q/%Y")
   ```

   This switches from `paste(.., sep="")` to `paste0`, a convenience function. Then, it removes the leading `"Q"` since really we don't keep it around, so why add it (other than perhaps declarative code). Last, it does a whole vector of strings at once.

(This is taking the data sight-unseen, so untested.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. The first method worked. I was able to append the column onto sloos_tighten and use that. The second method rendered the column "Period" all to NAs, however.

Comment: It's possible you have `factor`s, in which case `as.character` will help. If you need more help, then please remove all guessing and just give us sample data by posting the output from `dput(.)`. (Making us guess reduces the chances that our answers/suggestions will work.)